When using Caffeine Cache, what is the purpose of passing a CacheLoader into the build() method during cache creation?
I create a Cache use Caffeine.buider.build(), and put a CacheLoader in it.
        Cache<Integer,String> cache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
                .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .maximumSize(10000)
                .build(this::getCache);

I ask ChatGPT, it told me that when I use cache.get(key) method, and the key doesn't exist, it will use CacheLoader to generate a 'key-value' and put it into cache then return from get method.

But Caffeine doesn't have a method cache.get(key), it only have cache.get(key,Function).

This method will use Function when the value of key doesn't exist in Cache.
So,what is the purpose of passing a CacheLoader into the build() method during cache creation?
I ask ChatGPT, but it doesn't give any useful information

When you supply a CacheLoader, the return type is a LoadingCache which includes the get(key) method. Here is a tutorial.
